# changeover normally closed to normally open

Tags: switches, relay, normally-open

I have a switch that is used for setting tool lengths on CNC Mill.  The switch operates normally closed, and breaks the signal when a tool touches it, which sets the length via a macro.
The control however, sees this the opposite way, and is looking for the signal to set the length.
When I run the macro it immediately sees the signal, and sets a tool length, even though the tool hasn't had time to move and is no where near the switch.

What I am looking for is a relay that will switch this NC to an NO, and ideally this trigger would happen instantly so these dozens of tools can be set at higher speeds.
Is that a thing?  What is it called?

Here are the specs for the switch:
[image]

Hopefully this is something that is readily available, bonus points available if you can help me find one for sale!
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a photo of the switch?  Any chance that the switch has a normally open contact?

Comment: Wouldn't any relay do? Wire the output of your NC switch to the coil of a relay. It will be energised whenever the switch is not asserted. So the relay's NC output will be open when the switch is not and closed when it is.

Comment: @HeathRaftery 
I have very limited experience with this stuff so I'm pretty much looking for someone to tell me exactly what "format" I need and preferably even a link to a store where I can get it.  Can I get one that used the same power source as the switch?

When I look at relays online they all look the same to me :/
It would also be helpful if the switch operated as quickly as possible for better accuracy, I heard solid state relays might be a better fit for this application, but I'm not sure how to tell.

Comment: @PeterBennett
Heres the exact switch: Http://m.ebay.com/itm/201609561355

Comment: Ah righto. Sorry not willing to do that - would need to look at all sorts of other considerations like budget, power, safety, lead time, location, availability, physical interfaces, etc., etc. Too hard for me on a Q&A site. Just look at a bunch of relays, compare operating times, current and voltage ratings and see if you can get closer or come up with a more specific question. Good luck!